# Audit/log table cleanup - Adding the missing columns

Tags: sql, oracle, database-trigger

I have data tables and respective log tables which will capture all the CRUD transactions entered in the data tables using triggers.

For example:

```
Address data table
------------------
Address1
Address2
City
Country
Zipcode

Address log table
------------------
Address1
Address2
City
Country
```

The above is an example where the `zipcode` column exists in the data table but is missing from the log table. I have hundreds of tables to cross verify. Is any way or script which will get me all the missing columns in the log tables?

Comment: Look into `user_tab_columns`.

Comment: Thanks let me check it.